# GAS & Google Spreadsheet API v4 - Writing to file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using Apps Script and I've authorized Drive API and Sheets API for my code. First step, i'm using this to create a spreadsheet within my google drive.

```js
function createSS() {

  var ssName = 'TEST123';
  var parentFolder = '1MCQ7f7KUJ474FHA2IzyASV99Igz6aHEu';
  var resource = {
    title: ssName,
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{ id: parentFolder }]
  }
  var ss = Drive.Files.insert(resource);

}
```

Now I need to add some sheets and cell values. I'm guessing I should use the Sheets API to open the file by ID before editing. Is this correct? How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use the API for most things in sheets and drive, but rather the "Bean" commands (which are much nicer).

Comment: where are you hoping to run this command from? Does it live in a google sheet?

Comment: @J. G.  Running from G Suite Developer Hub. I'll want to eventually pull some reports and print them to Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SpreadsheetApp to create, then moving the file once created seems to be my working solution. No need to get the file id.

```js
function createSS() {    
  // gets first folder with the given foldername
  var destFolder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName('GAS Logs').next(); 

  // create spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('TEST123');

  // get fist sheet and rename it
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.setName('SHEET123');

  // Add cell data
  sheet.appendRow(['Do','Something', 'Here']);
  sheet.appendRow(['Thanks','For','The', 'Help!']);

  // Make a copy to destination folder and remove the original file
  var copySS = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  destFolder.addFile(copySS);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copySS);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- To retrieve your newly created file, you can proceed as:

```
  var ss = Drive.Files.insert(resource);
  var url=ss.alternateLink; 
  var id=ss.id;
```

- In the next step, you can use both the SpreadsheetApp and Sheets API to add sheets and values.

> Sample with SpreadsheetApp:

```
  var ID="XXX";
  var sheetName="XXX";
  var values=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  ss.insertSheet('sheetName');
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('sheetName');
  var range=sheet.getRange("A1:C2");

  range.setValues(values);
```

> Sample with Sheets API (please enable first Sheets Advanced service in the GAS editor):

```
  var ID="XXX";
  var sheetName="XXX";
  var values="1,2,3, \n 4,5,6";
  var resource = {requests: [
            {
                "addSheet": {
                  "properties": {
                  "title": sheetName,
                  "sheetId": 3
                  } 
               }
             },{
                "pasteData": {
                  "data": values,
                  "type": "PASTE_NORMAL",
                  "delimiter": ",",
                  "coordinate": {
                  "sheetId": 3,
                  "rowIndex": 0,
                  "columnIndex": 0
                   }
                  }
                }
              ]
             };     
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ID)
```

References:

- [insertSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer,Object))
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [BatchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request):

Comment: The above code should work perfect for my needs except my original problem stays the same. I need to figure out how to get the ID or URL of the newly created spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did not expect it would be that simple.